# Escape '<' '>' in property key file

Tags: java, properties, escaping

I want to escape the `<` and `>` from the value in my key in the properties file.

I tried it with backslashes, but that don't seem to work:

```
footer.madeby=\<b\>test\</b\>
```

How can I escape special characters in Java property keys?

Comment: *Why* do you want to escape those characters? They don't have any special meaning in a properties file.

Comment: Because I have a multilanguage system that uses the keys in the property files. I could seperate the string into several properties, but I thought it would be easier if I it was possible to just escape those characters.

Comment: Can you use unicode "%" escaping or html entities?

Comment: @KidDiamond: you didn't understand Jon's comment. Those characters don't need to be escaped in properties files. They need to be escaped in HTML files. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the characters you are trying to escape are special. The following code will load and print your property just fine if you omit the backslashes:

```
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("<name of bundle>");
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("footer.madeby"));
```

If you are unsure of which characters need escaping, try to write the property set to a file using one of the the [`Properties.store`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) methods. You can write a small sandbox class that will write your properties to a file for you. Whichever escapes Java puts in for you will be the right ones:

```
Properties myProperties = new Properties();
myProperties.put("footer.madeby", "<b>test</b>");
try(Writer writer = new FileWriter("<your properties name>") {
    myProperties.store(writer, null);
}
```